# How to add optional ngModelGroup in angular forms?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-forms

I'm facing issue with adding optional `ngModelGroup` in angular forms. I do know about the usage of `ngModelGroup` in angular forms, but struggling to find a way to make it optional.

I tried passing `false`, `null`, `undefined` and still not working

Please find the code sample below and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelgroup) link

expected form object

```
{
"firstName": "",
"lastName": "",
"zip": "",
"street": "",
"city": ""}
```

Any help is appreciated

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

/*
  1. <fieldset ngModelGroup="address">  add address control object to form
  2. <fieldset [attr.ngModelGroup]="true ? 'address' : null">  not working
  3. <fieldset [ngModelGroup]="false ? 'address' : null">  

  so how to make ngModelGroup optional here ????
*/

@Component({
  selector: 'address',
  template: `
    <fieldset [ngModelGroup]="false ? 'address' : null">
      <div>
        <label>Zip:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Street:</label>
        <input type="text" name="street" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" ngModel>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  `,
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class AddressComponent  {}
```

Comment: Why would you want ngModelGroup to be optional ?

Comment: Lets say I have developed the re-usable component, and I'm going to add this feature to the existing component, such that it should be backward compatibility.

Comment: Why do you want ngModelGroup at all? If you want a flat form value object then  the most logical would be to not use ngModelGroup .

Answer (score 0):

You can always map the forms value to an object that fits your needs...

```
getFlatFormValues(value: any) {
    const flatObject = {
      "firstName": value.firstName,
      "lastName": value.lastName,
    }

    if (value.address) {
        return {
          ...flatObject,
          ...value.address
        }
    }

    return flatObject;
  }
```

See working example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngmodelgroup-hgbro7

Comment: Appreciate the solution, but this is not what I'm looking for. I really want this change to be reflected in `form.value`

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to apply directives (e.g. the ngModelGroup directive) dynamically. You could add two variants in the template with and without ngModelGroup and use ngIf to show the right one. 

You could look into ReactiveForms and build your form structure (FormGroups) dynamically. But it will come with `if else` code in the class and ngIf in the template. I think it will be much more easy if you simply transform the form.value before another party is using it (as mentioned in my answer :))

Comment: The problem is people consuming the component will use `form.value` directly, so unless making this change inside `form.value`, there is no other answer. I could try *ngIf though but do not want to go in this route.

Comment: How do people consuming the component access the form instance?

Comment: I think the component consumers should not access `form.value` directly. Maybe you should consider to use an `@Output()` to inform the parent component about the new form value. Or you could write the form value to an angular service which exposes an public API to access the form value. With both variants you can map the form.value to whatever object you need before it is consumed. 

The public interface of your component should not rely too much on the structure of `form.value`, because it is quite common that the form structure changes with new requirements.